# Why does Google+ API method people.me still work?

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-people-api

My web-app is using Google+ API method called `people.me`. I was notified via E-Mail that this Api is going to shutdown on March 7. I was given a list of methods used by me in that Api and this was the only method in the list.

Today it's March 11 and the method keeps working correctly. Why? Maybe I understood something wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the top of a lot of the methods in the Google+ documentation you will see this

> The Google+ People API list endpoint is deprecated. Consider using the Google People API instead.

On some of the methods that does not appear. IMO that is because some of these endpoints never actual read from the Google+ api rather they were reading from the google people api all along and just got a plus in the name.  They may at some point have read from it and were moved when they redid google contacts. The people.me endpoint is part of the google people api and not the google plus api

[People.get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get)

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/userId
```

is the same as

[people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)

```
GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/{resourceName=people/*}
```

The data for both of those end points comes from google contacts.

Now again this is just my opinion i have emailed google several times and the only answer i got back is we will look into it.  I would wait until April if they are still live i guess we are good.

Comment: 1) These are two different APIs with different urls. `people.googleapis.com` vs `www.googleapis.com/plus`. My url contains `plus` explicitly. 2) I was notified that I do use Plus and should migrate. And this method was the only one listed. 3) Google dev panel still shows that I still use Google+ Api with no errors.

Comment: there was some arguments as to if this endpoint would go or not.  My bet was on it staying since it read form people api others says it would go because like you they said it was plus.   I have emailed google a number of times and they never gave me any information about this endpoint.   I have chosen to continue to use it and watch.

Comment: This makes the question really unanswerable. Thank you for your help anyway. Maybe close it then? Or maybe a google official could pass by the question.

Comment: Its not possible to close an question after you get an answer.  Leave it until after April when google+ shutdowns.  Then we will know if my theory was correct.